# GIT Committed Files Are Missing

Tags: git, version-control

My local commits and pushing seems to be working onto the remote system as I see all the proper messages when committing and pushing:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\helloworld\test\testlocalgit\test [master +2 ~0 -0 !]> git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 12 commits.
( use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Untracked files:
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    gittesting_where.php
    test/test/

 nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
 C:\xampp\htdocs\helloworld\test\testlocalgit\test [master +2 ~0 -0 !]> git add gittesting_where.php
 C:\xampp\htdocs\helloworld\test\testlocalgit\test [master +1 ~0 -0 | +1 ~0 -0 !]> git commit -m "new file to test git on development system 11-10-2014"
 [master 43ae93c] new file to test git on development system 11-10-2014
 1 file changed, 6 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 gittesting_where.php
 C:\xampp\htdocs\helloworld\test\testlocalgit\test [master +1 ~0 -0 !]> git push develop master
 Warning: Permanently added 'develop.livm.net,192.168.19.70' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
 root@develop.livm.net's password:
 Counting objects: 4, done.
 Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
 Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
 Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 422 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
 Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
 To ssh://root@develop.livm.net:/var/www/html/demo/iMedicWare/nsg/helloworld/test/.git/
 7481ddf..43ae93c  master -> master
 C:\xampp\htdocs\helloworld\test\testlocalgit\test [master +1 ~0 -0 !]>
```

When I go on the remote system in the git log, I see the code has been pushed on the remote system. But I do NOT see the pushed file there:

```
 [root@develop test]# pwd
 /var/www/html/demo/iMedicWare/nsg/helloworld/test

 [root@develop test]# git branch
 * master

 [root@develop test]# git log
 commit 43ae93c981ab25d13033e974accb2f1f242f2621
 Author: meauthor<meauthor@email.com>
 Date:   Mon Nov 10 14:46:55 2014 -0500

 new file to test git on development system 11-10-2014

 [root@develop test]# git show 43ae93c981ab25d13033e974accb2f1f242f2621
 commit 43ae93c981ab25d13033e974accb2f1f242f2621
 Author: meauthor <meauthor@email.com>
 Date:   Mon Nov 10 14:46:55 2014 -0500

 new file to test git on development system 11-10-2014

 diff --git a/gittesting_where.php b/gittesting_where.php
 new file mode 100644
 index 0000000..e4d1e76
 --- /dev/null
 +++ b/gittesting_where.php
 @@ -0,0 +1,6 @@
 +<?php
 +
 +       echo("New file to test git 11-10-2014");
 +
 +
 +?>

 [root@develop test]# find . -name "gittesting_where.php" -print   
 [root@develop test]# 
 [root@develop test]# pwd
 /var/www/html/demo/iMedicWare/nsg/helloworld/test

 [root@develop test]# ls -la
 total 44
 drwxr-xr-x 8 root   root   4096 Nov  7 12:37 .
 drwxr-xr-x 4 apache apache 4096 Nov  7 10:19 ..
 drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root   4096 Nov  7 12:37 branches
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root   root     66 Nov  7 12:37 config
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root   root     73 Nov  7 12:37 description
 drwxr-xr-x 8 root   root   4096 Nov  7 15:11 .git
 -rw-r--r-- 1 root   root     23 Nov  7 12:37 HEAD
 drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root   4096 Nov  7 12:37 hooks
 drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root   4096 Nov  7 12:37 info
 drwxr-xr-x 4 root   root   4096 Nov  7 12:37 objects
 drwxr-xr-x 4 root   root   4096 Nov  7 12:37 refs
 [root@develop test]#

 [root@develop test]# cd .git/
 [root@develop .git]# pwd
 /var/www/html/demo/iMedicWare/nsg/helloworld/test/.git
 [root@develop .git]# ls -la
 total 48
 drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 Nov  7 15:11 .
 drwxr-xr-x  8 root root 4096 Nov  7 12:37 ..
 -rw-r--r--  1 root root   92 Nov  4 14:44 11-04-2014_config_copy
 drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Nov  3 09:26 branches
 -rw-r--r--  1 root root  153 Nov  5 11:53 config
 -rw-r--r--  1 root root   32 Nov  7 15:11 description
 -rw-r--r--  1 root root   23 Nov  3 09:26 HEAD
 drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Nov  3 09:26 hooks
 drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4096 Nov  3 09:26 info
 drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Nov  4 15:53 logs
 drwxr-xr-x 82 root root 4096 Nov 10 14:47 objects
 drwxr-xr-x  4 root root 4096 Nov  3 09:26 refs
 [root@develop .git]#
```

Here is my local .gitconfig

```
 [user]
     name = meauthor
     email = meauthor@email.com
 [remote "develop"]
     url = ssh://root@develop.livm.net:/var/www/html/demo/iMedicWare/nsg/helloworld/test/.git/
     fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/develop/*
```

What am I doing wrong that I am not seeing the pushed file on the remote system?

Comment: It seems to me that your remote is a bare repository. In those you won't see the files themselves

Comment: So where are the files? This does not make any sense to me. In the remote repository I have shown, this is the application. So I need those application files so it can run on the server.

Comment: http://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/ maybe can help you

Comment: I need help. As none of these answers answer my question. Ultimately I need a tutorial/help on setting up a remote repo where the application will live and run as well as developers pushing changes to it. The application must run on the remote server so it can be viewed on a web browser. Does anyone have some tutorial that can guide me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I needed to add a hook in my git directory. Now my local and remote GIT works great! I used post-update hook:

```
 [root@develop hooks]# more post-update
 #!/bin/sh
 #
 # An example hook script to prepare a packed repository for use over
 # dumb transports.
 #
 # To enable this hook, rename this file to "post-update".
 # exec git update-server-info

 GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/html/demo/iMedicWare/nsg/websiteactualwebdir git checkout -f
```

I found and followed these two tutorials to guide me on this:
   http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto
   http://danielmiessler.com/study/git/

I needed to learn a bit more about bare versus regular repositories and hooks, which is what I originally missed.